How to check if a resource has finished uploading to the GPU
I'm developing an app with a big 3D world where meshes/textures are uploaded and immediately drawn when you move to a new area. The simplified code for rendering a frame looks like this (I'm using Dawn):
// Start frame
commandEncoder = wgpuDeviceCreateCommandEncoder(device, nullptr);

// Create and upload mesh
vertexBuffer = wgpuDeviceCreateBuffer(device, &desc);
wgpuQueueWriteBuffer(queue, vertexBuffer, 0, vertices, desc.size);

// Start render pass
// ...

// Draw mesh
wgpuRenderPassEncoderSetVertexBuffer(renderPassEncoder, 0, vertexBuffer, 0, desc.size);
wgpuRenderPassEncoderDraw(renderPassEncoder, numElements, 1, firstElement, 0);

// End render pass
// ...

// Submit queue and end frame
auto commandBuffer = wgpuCommandEncoderFinish(commandEncoder, nullptr);
wgpuQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &commandBuffer);
wgpuCommandBufferRelease(commandBuffer);
wgpuCommandEncoderRelease(commandEncoder);
wgpuSwapChainPresent(swapchain);

The problem is that (if I understand correctly how the GPU works) the GPU would stall between the upload and the draw until the mesh has finished uploading.
I checked with RenderDoc how this is translated by Dawn to actual D3D12 commands and there is a ResourceBarrier between the CopyBufferRegion and the DrawInstanced which would leave the pipeline waiting until the resource transitions from D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DST to D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_VERTEX_AND_CONSTANT_BUFFER.
I thought of using onSubmittedWorkDone to detect from the CPU if the upload has finished and wait to send any draw commands until then. However the documentation in that link suggests that it shouldn't be used except in two very particular cases (none of them is the one here), which leads me to think I'm on the wrong path.

You shouldn't have to worry about it. WebGPU is supposed to deal with all of that for you.

Why do you need to know when the upload as finished?

@gman I would like to know a little of what happens under the hood and how WebGPU solves this problem (if this problem even exists, since I might be missing something important of how GPUs work).

@FrankYellin Because if the GPU runs a draw command using the resource before it has loaded it would stall the pipeline until it's ready, but if I knew from the CPU side wether it's loaded I could wait until then to enqueue the draw.

What do you gain by waiting? Just enqueue the draw and it happens when it happens.

What worries me is not the loading mesh but the rest of the meshes that are enqueued for drawing along it. They would have to wait for the mesh ahead in the queue to finish loading, so there would be a framerate drop every time you enter a new area of the map and stuff gets uploaded to the GPU. That's why I'm thinking of this delayed drawing thing as a solution.

(1) It's not common to upload meshes every frame. (2) there's only 1 queue currently so you can't issue an upload command and issue other commands that run while the upload happens. They happen in order, period. (3) There is a discusson on making WebGPU multi-threaded, possibly with multiple queues. If and when that happens you could possibly upload in one thread/queue while rendering in another. That's likely a year or two away as browsers are trying to ship version 1 of the API. And, multi-threading requires coordinating with whatever wasm does.

@gman Thanks for the explanation! So there's little I can do... Maybe by switching to Vulkan I could tackle these low-level problems but I'd rather not.

If you are using webgpu natively via dawn or wgpu there might be ways to be multi-threaded already but via the official spec it's still TBD
